# vsFTPd default uploaded file permissions on Ubuntu not working

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, chmod, vsftpd

I have a Server running *Ubuntu 12.10 x64*, and the last version of vsFTPd.

My user example.com has its home folder set on `/var/www/example.com`,

I created a public_html folder inside and gave `777` permisions to it, and removed the writing permissions of the home user folder. Everything is working well but:

Every file I upload by FTP (using SmartFTP) gets a chmod of 0.

My `vsftpd.conf` had only one line related:

```
local_umask=022.
```

I've tried to change to:

```
file_open_mode=777
local_umask=002
```

So my files would get `775` as soon as uploaded.

But only my uploaded folders are getting `775` permissions.

My uploaded files get `1411 permissions`

Can someone help me solving that?

Comment: you must to give permission to the FTP user.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got my answer:

As the www-data is the user responsible for the webserver and your normal user is responsible for the ftp server, you need first to make them both members of the same group: the group www-data.

**Creating custom User:**

`useradd –d /var/www/asasd.com -g www-data -m yourusername`
this way the home directory will be the */var/www/asasd.com* and your user will be in the **www-data** group.

after this, change the user pass by typing `passwd`.

Then, you need to create a *public_html* folder inside your **yourusername** home folder, as the FTP wont be able to write in the root of your home folder, you have to create a subfolder.

Remove write permissions of your **yourusername** folder
`chmod a-w /var/www/asasd.com`

Then, apply new permissions for the subfolder:
`chmod -R 775 /var/www/asasd.com/public_html`
(note you must use 775 chmod because you need group write permissions, not user write permissions, as you want the whole group (ftp and www-data) being able to write)
Then, own the folder for the **www-data**
`chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/asasd.com/public_html`

That way you must be able to use FTP and have a Webserver working.

Good luck!

Funny  this info is so hard to find. Are people not sharing knowledge anymore?

Comment: "you need first to make them both members of the same group: the group www-data" How to put my ftp user in the group www-data?

Comment: Worked perfect. Thanks @lucasmx

Answer (score 14):

I ended up using

```
file_open_mode=0777
local_umask=022
```

on the vsftpd.conf. The problem was that both FTP user and www-data user needed permissions to write, so i had to join www-data and ftpuser to www-data usergroup, and CHMOD -R 775 all the files on /var/www - that way, with 775 CHMOD, the group would have permission to read, write and execute. Now its working perfectly.

Comment: do not forget to restart the FTP server: sudo service vsftpd restart

Answer (score 0):

I also had problem like the file permission is changed when i upload a file through my ftp. This is fixed with one line change in my `vsftpd.conf`

`local_umask=val(like 022,007,etc.,)`

Comment: Care to improve and open this a little bit? Why is this *better* than the previous alternatives and what does it actually *do*, since this kind of syntax is not described in the manual page at all: `local_umask` has to be single value, and it must have `0` as a prefix for octal value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ftp or anonymous user to upload files, please use below lines to set the upload file permission to 644 in `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf` file

```
file_open_mode=0666
anon_umask=022
```

Final permission is  `666-022 = 644`.

Answer (score -4):

you need to change the ownership of that file:

```
chown root:root /home/username
```